# ownCloud client for android Login fail with android 4.3

Tags: android, cloud, accountmanager, android-4.3-jelly-bean, owncloud

I'm working on cloud project with ownCloud source. here the link in [Github](https://github.com/owncloud/android)

It's work well on many device even emulator but there is Account problem on Android 4.3 phones and can't sync with account. I Googled so much but can't find a proper solution.

I get this on my Logcat when I try to upload a file:

```
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221): calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock and/or ANRs
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221): java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.ensureNotOnMainThread(AccountManager.java:1423)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$200(AccountManager.java:145)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.internalGetResult(AccountManager.java:1505)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1542)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1463)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(AccountManager.java:848)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at com.owncloud.android.lib.common.accounts.AccountUtils.getCredentialsForAccount(AccountUtils.java:189)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at com.owncloud.android.lib.common.OwnCloudAccount.<init>(OwnCloudAccount.java:59)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at com.owncloud.android.ui.activity.FileDisplayActivity$SyncBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(FileDisplayActivity.java:927)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
09-14 12:47:45.685: E/AccountManager(12221):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also Installed owncloud workaround from [googleplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.owncloud.android.workaround.accounts) but problem is still remains. :(

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace suggests that you are calling `blockingGetAuthToken` from the main thread and this is not allowed.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#blockingGetAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) say:

> This method may block while a network request completes, and must
>   never be made from the main thread.

This means that when you call `blockingGetAuthToken` this function will not return until it has fetched the auth token. If you don't call this method from a separate thread it means that your whole application will freeze until `blockingGetAuthToken` have finished. Since getting the auth token may require a network request it can sometimes take a long time (several seconds) before it is fetched.

Since this has worked for you before I assume that previous versions of Android have allowed this, but that Android 4.3 have started to throw an expectation if it detects that `blockingGetAuthToken` is called from the main thread.

You need to either call blockingGetAuthToken from a separate thread or use the asynchronous [GetAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback<android.os.Bundle>,%20android.os.Handler)) in order to not block the UI while the token is being fetched. If you don't want to deal with multiple threads you could call `GetAuthToken` instead of `blockingGetAuthToken` and provide a callback that should be called later when the token has been fetched.

[Here is one example](http://blog.tomtasche.at/2013/05/google-oauth-on-android-using.html) that uses GetAuthToken, I haven't tried it myself but maybe it can show you how it can be used.

Comment: would you explain me more and simple?

Comment: @Kenji, I've updated the answer with some more details, I hope it helps you.

Comment: where do you mean. in accountUtils or ownCloudClientFactory?

Comment: In accountUtils since that's what is callign blockingGetAuthToken according to the stack trace.